# Undefined method/instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning RoR and working on a simple app to share posts. My trouble is creating the posts and displaying them on a separate page(not sure where my error is). When a "user" goes to post an "event" I get an undefined method:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
12:      <%= render @events %>

I thought I had defined the method properly, but I guess not.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is the [controller in question](https://github.com/latinforadapt/grmbly_app/blob/master/app/controllers/events_controller.rb#L9):

```
  def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
    if @event.save
      flash[:success] = "Event Shared"
      redirect_to root_path
    #else
    #  render 'pages/about'
    end


    #@event = Event.new         what I had before
    #@title = "Create An Event"
  end
```

You set `@event` in there but not `@events`. Instance variables are created on first use and default to `nil` so in your view, when you say this:

```
<%= render @events %>
```

you're creating `@events` right there and it will be `nil`. Perhaps you want:

```
<%= render @event %>
```

Comment: I first tried singular "@event" and received an error with that as well. The aspect that confuses me is that my user controller [here](https://github.com/latinforadapt/grmbly_app/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb) has a singular @user, but it displays on the users index page [here](https://github.com/latinforadapt/grmbly_app/blob/master/app/views/users/index.html.erb)

Comment: This is the error it gives, so I think you are right. Should the :content be defined in the controller? I feel like it's just one correction short of posting. Thanks for your help. Also, my repo is updated to my most current version.

undefined method `content' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x11083f6d8>

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <div class="details">
4:  <h5><a href="#">Students Vs Food!</a></h5>
5:  <p>
6:  <%=  @event.content %>
7:  </p>
8: </div>
9: </div>


Trace of template inclusion: app/views/events/show.html.erb

Comment: @Alekx: Your `UsersController#index` has `@users`. And in `EventsController#show`, your `Event.paginate(:page => params[:page])` returns a list of events when `show` is normally handling a single event (`@event = Event.find(params[:id])`).